# Create a slider to dynamically display distance two lines in an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, jquery-ui

[image]

I am new jQuery. I want to create a slider which will move the green line along the x axis of the image as you can see in the image. From the image you can see there are two lines (line 1, line 2). I have the values (x,y) of the lines in a JSON objects.

As I move the slider, I want to show the distance between the two lines in the text box provided right next to the image by iterating through the JSON objects provided. I want the distance to change dynamically as I move around the slider over the image.

I came across different kinds of jQuery UI sliders. I couldn't find any examples related to my need. Therefore, asking for help here. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any existing code? If you do, could you possibly create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) so we can have a play around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.tooltip {
 width: 1px;
 height: 512;
    position: absolute;
    bottom:100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>
 This is an example of slider feature
</title>
</head>
<body>
 <img src="https://s31.postimg.org/vkcjhvwgr/output.png">
 <div class="vr">&nbsp;</div>
 <div id="json-slider"></div>
 <input id="distance" type="text">

<!-- include the jQuery and jQuery UI scripts -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/flick/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
 var ilmJson = [
 [4.0, 113.0],
 [5.0, 114.0],
 [6.0, 114.0],
 [7.0, 114.0],
 [8.0, 113.0],
 [9.0, 114.0],
 [10.0, 114.0],
 [11.0, 114.0],
 [12.0, 114.0],
 [13.0, 114.0],
 [14.0, 114.0],
 [15.0, 114.0],
 [16.0, 114.0],
 [17.0, 114.0],
 [18.0, 115.0],
 [19.0, 115.0],
 [20.0, 115.0],
 [21.0, 115.0],
 [22.0, 115.0],
 [23.0, 115.0],
 [24.0, 114.0],
 [25.0, 114.0],
 [26.0, 115.0],
 [27.0, 115.0],
 [28.0, 115.0],
 [29.0, 115.0],
 [30.0, 115.0],
 [31.0, 115.0],
 [32.0, 115.0],
 [33.0, 116.0],
 [34.0, 116.0],
 [35.0, 116.0],
 [36.0, 115.0],
 [37.0, 116.0],
 [38.0, 116.0],
 [39.0, 116.0],
 [40.0, 116.0],
 [41.0, 116.0],
 [42.0, 116.0],
 [43.0, 116.0],
 [44.0, 116.0],
 [45.0, 116.0],
 [46.0, 116.0],
 [47.0, 116.0],
 [48.0, 116.0],
 [49.0, 116.0],
 [50.0, 116.0],
 [51.0, 116.0],
 [52.0, 116.0],
 [53.0, 116.0],
 [54.0, 116.0],
 [55.0, 116.0],
 [56.0, 116.0],
 [57.0, 116.0],
 [58.0, 117.0],
 [59.0, 117.0],
 [60.0, 117.0],
 [61.0, 117.0],
 [62.0, 117.0],
 [63.0, 117.0],
 [64.0, 117.0],
 [65.0, 117.0],
 [66.0, 117.0],
 [67.0, 117.0],
 [68.0, 117.0],
 [69.0, 117.0],
 [70.0, 117.0],
 [71.0, 117.0],
 [72.0, 117.0],
 [73.0, 117.0],
 [74.0, 117.0],
 [75.0, 117.0],
 [76.0, 117.0],
 [77.0, 117.0],
 [78.0, 117.0],
 [79.0, 117.0],
 [80.0, 117.0],
 [81.0, 117.0],
 [82.0, 117.0],
 [83.0, 117.0],
 [84.0, 117.0],
 [85.0, 117.0],
 [86.0, 117.0],
 [87.0, 118.0],
 [88.0, 118.0],
 [89.0, 118.0],
 [90.0, 117.0]
];

var rpeJson = [
 [4.0, 167.0],
 [5.0, 167.0],
 [6.0, 167.0],
 [7.0, 167.0],
 [8.0, 168.0],
 [9.0, 168.0],
 [10.0, 168.0],
 [11.0, 168.0],
 [12.0, 168.0],
 [13.0, 168.0],
 [14.0, 168.0],
 [15.0, 168.0],
 [16.0, 168.0],
 [17.0, 168.0],
 [18.0, 168.0],
 [19.0, 168.0],
 [20.0, 168.0],
 [21.0, 169.0],
 [22.0, 168.0],
 [23.0, 168.0],
 [24.0, 169.0],
 [25.0, 169.0],
 [26.0, 170.0],
 [27.0, 169.0],
 [28.0, 169.0],
 [29.0, 169.0],
 [30.0, 168.0],
 [31.0, 169.0],
 [32.0, 169.0],
 [33.0, 169.0],
 [34.0, 170.0],
 [35.0, 170.0],
 [36.0, 170.0],
 [37.0, 170.0],
 [38.0, 170.0],
 [39.0, 171.0],
 [40.0, 170.0],
 [41.0, 170.0],
 [42.0, 171.0],
 [43.0, 171.0],
 [44.0, 170.0],
 [45.0, 170.0],
 [46.0, 171.0],
 [47.0, 171.0],
 [48.0, 171.0],
 [49.0, 171.0],
 [50.0, 171.0],
 [51.0, 171.0],
 [52.0, 171.0],
 [53.0, 171.0],
 [54.0, 172.0],
 [55.0, 171.0],
 [56.0, 172.0],
 [57.0, 171.0],
 [58.0, 172.0],
 [59.0, 172.0],
 [60.0, 172.0],
 [61.0, 172.0],
 [62.0, 172.0],
 [63.0, 172.0],
 [64.0, 172.0],
 [65.0, 173.0],
 [66.0, 173.0],
 [67.0, 173.0],
 [68.0, 173.0],
 [69.0, 173.0],
 [70.0, 173.0],
 [71.0, 173.0],
 [72.0, 173.0],
 [73.0, 173.0],
 [74.0, 173.0],
 [75.0, 173.0],
 [76.0, 173.0],
 [77.0, 174.0],
 [78.0, 174.0],
 [79.0, 174.0],
 [80.0, 174.0],
 [81.0, 174.0],
 [82.0, 174.0],
 [83.0, 174.0],
 [84.0, 174.0],
 [85.0, 174.0],
 [86.0, 174.0],
 [87.0, 174.0],
 [88.0, 174.0],
 [89.0, 174.0],
 [90.0, 175.0]
];

$("#json-slider").slider({
 value: 0,
 min: 0,
 max: 1023,
 step: 1,
 slide: function(event, ui){
  var dist = rpeJson[ui.value][1] - ilmJson[ui.value][1];
  $("#distance").val(dist);
  var curValue = ui.value;
  var tooltip = '<div class="tooltip"></div>';

     $('.ui-slider-handle').html(tooltip); //attach tooltip to the slider handle
 }
});
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I could not post the entire JSON here due to some limitations. But the feature is working for me currently. Hopefully, this helps someone.